# Join Nearest Date

Tags: mysql

I have read through a ton of responses on here but nothing is working quite as well as I would like.  I currently have a working query that includes 2 sub queries, the problem is that it takes about 10 seconds to execute.  I was wondering if there is any way to make this go quicker, maybe with a join. I just can't seem to get my head out of the box it is in.  Please let me know your thoughts.

Here is the working query:

```
Select concat(a.emp_firstname, ' ', a.emp_lastname) as names 
  , if(if (a.emp_gender = 1, 'Male', a.emp_gender)=2, 'Female', 
    if (a.emp_gender = 1, 'Male', a.emp_gender)) as emp_gender 
  , c.name 
  , a.emp_work_telephone
  , a.emp_hm_telephone, a.emp_work_email
  , a.custom7, a.employee_id 
  , a.city_code, a.provin_code, d.name as status, 
  (SELECT cast(concat(DATE_FORMAT(e.app_datetime, '%H:%i'), ' ', e.app_facility) as char(100)) 
     FROM li_appointments.li_appointments as e where e.terp_id = a.employee_id
     and e.app_datetime <= str_to_date('06/26/13 at 3:20 PM', '%m/%d/%Y at %h:%i %p') 
     and date(e.app_datetime) = date(str_to_date('06/26/13 at 3:20 PM', '%m/%d/%Y at %h:%i %p')) 
     order by e.app_datetime desc limit 1) as prevapp, 
  (SELECT cast(concat(DATE_FORMAT(e.app_datetime, '%H:%i'), ' ', e.app_facility) as char(100)) 
     FROM li_appointments.li_appointments as e 
     where e.terp_id = a.employee_id 
     and e.app_datetime > str_to_date('06/26/13 at 3:20 PM', '%m/%d/%Y at %h:%i %p') 
     and date(e.app_datetime) = date(str_to_date('06/26/13 at 3:20 PM', '%m/%d/%Y at %h:%i %p')) 
     order by e.app_datetime desc limit 1) as nextapp 
from hs_hr_employee as a 
Join hs_hr_emp_skill as b on a.emp_number = b.emp_number 
Join ohrm_skill as c on b.skill_id = c.id 
Join orangehrm_li.ohrm_employment_status as d on a.emp_status = d.id 
where c.name like '%Arabic%' 
and d.name = 'Active' order by rand();
```

`EXPLAIN` results:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id |    select_type     | table |  type  |    possible_keys    |    key     | key_len |            ref            | rows  |                    Extra                     |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | d     | ALL    | PRIMARY             |            |         |                           |    10 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | ref    | PRIMARY,emp_status  | emp_status |       5 | orangehrm_li.d.id         |    48 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | b     | ref    | emp_number,skill_id | emp_number |       4 | orangehrm_li.a.emp_number |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY    |       4 | orangehrm_li.b.skill_id   |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | e     | ALL    |                     |            |         |                           | 28165 | Using where; Using filesort                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | e     | ALL    |                     |            |         |                           | 28165 | Using where; Using filesort                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: To look a bit deeper, please post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT (yourquery)`.

Comment: What happens if you remove your order by rand()? While I can see how it may be useful, it is probably bringing your database to it's knees if your record selection is large.

Comment: Joe, the results are usually around 20 - 30 rows.  In my testing the rand() does not seem to be the problem.  When I remove the sub querires the total duration is less than .02 secconds.

Comment: The app_datetime is a datetime.  The query runs in php and I had it echo the actual query generated for further testing.

Comment: Bjoern, thank you for your help here is the result:
1, PRIMARY, d, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 10, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1, PRIMARY, a, ref, PRIMARY,emp_status, emp_status, 5, orangehrm_li.d.id, 48, Using where
1, PRIMARY, b, ref, emp_number,skill_id, emp_number, 4, orangehrm_li.a.emp_number, 1, 
1, PRIMARY, c, eq_ref, PRIMARY, PRIMARY, 4, orangehrm_li.b.skill_id, 1, Using where
3, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, e, ALL, , , , , 28165, Using where; Using filesort
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, e, ALL, , , , , 28165, Using where; Using filesort

Comment: **Tip one**: Never convert the column in a query. Instead of `WHERE DATE(e.app_datetime) = DATE(...)` do `WHERE e.app_datetime BETWEEN @date1 and @date2`, otherwise the DB engine cannot use an index. **Tip two**: use correct multi-column indexes to make the sub-query a single seek operation. I would recommend an index over `(app_datetime ASC, terp_id ASC)` on `li_appointments.li_appointments`. **Tip three**: Work with @variables instead of repeating yourself so verbosely with all those dates. **Tip four**: Use ISO 8601 dates. http://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: Tomalak, I tried your suggestions, the first did not make any difference, however when I added the index the time increased to an average of 18 seconds, when I removed the index the time went down to 3 seconds.  Any idea why?

Comment: is there an auto-increment ID on your appointments table to work with?  If so, what is it...

Comment: DRapp, yes it is app_id.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables appear small enough to do as I have done here.  First, the inner-most query starts with all employees and did TWO left-joins immediately to the appointment table... By getting a MAX() of the appointments less than the date in question gets the "Previous Appointment", and getting the MIN() appointment AFTER the date in question gets the "Next Appointment".  So now, for a single person, I have both their ID and possible previous and next appointments based on their specific times.

Now, I take that result and re-join first to the appointment tables (left joined again) but this time based on same person (Terp_ID) AND their respective Previous and Next appointments date/time.  This would only be a problem if you had multiple entries with the exact same date/time for a single person, and that would just result in multiple records.

So now, I have each person with the specifics of previous and next appointments available.

The rest is simple joining to the other tables to get only employee status of "Active", and the skill set of "Arabic" criteria (which I have at their respective JOIN criteria), otherwise you could just move these to a WHERE clause.

As for the "Date/Time" basis of the query, I used @variable once so it could be used against both left-joins to appointments.  Finally, I grabbed the respective fields you wanted.  This SHOULD work, yet without your data, might need some tweaking.

```
SELECT 
      EmpPrevNext.Employee_ID,
      EmpPrevNext.PrevApnt,
      EmpPrevNext.NextApnt,
      concat(Emp2.emp_firstname, ' ', Emp2.emp_lastname) as names,
      if ( Emp2.emp_gender = 1, 'Male', 'Female' ) as emp_gender, 
      Emp2.emp_work_telephone, 
      Emp2.emp_hm_telephone, 
      Emp2.emp_work_email, 
      Emp2.custom7, 
      Emp2.city_code, 
      Emp2.provin_code, 
      cast( concat( DATE_FORMAT(PriorApp2.app_datetime, '%H:%i'), ' ', PriorApp2.app_facility) as char(100)) 
            as PriorAppointment,
      cast( concat( DATE_FORMAT(NextApp2.app_datetime, '%H:%i'), ' ', NextApp2.app_facility) as char(100)) 
            as NextAppointment,
      EStat.`name` as EmployeeStatus,
      Skill.`name` as SkillName
   FROM
      ( SELECT
              Emp.Employee_ID,
              MAX( PriorApp.app_DateTime ) as PrevApnt,
              MIN( NextApp.app_DateTime ) as NextApnt
           from 
              ( select @DateBasis := '06/26/13 at 3:20 PM' ) sqlvars,
              hs_hr_employee as Emp
                 LEFT JOIN li_appointments.li_appointments as PriorApp
                    ON Emp.Employee_ID = NextApp.Terp_ID
                    AND PriorApp.app_DateTime <= @DateBasis
                 LEFT JOIN li_appointments.li_appointments as NextApp
                    ON Emp.Employee_ID = NextApp.Terp_ID
                    AND NextApp.app_DateTime > @DateBasis
           group by
              Emp.Employee_ID ) EmpPrevNext

         LEFT JOIN li_appointments.li_appointments as PriorApp2
            ON EmpPrevNext.Employee_ID = PriorApp2.Terp_ID
           AND EmpPrevNext.PrevApnt = PriorApp2.app_DateTime

         LEFT JOIN li_appointments.li_appointments as NextApp2
            ON EmpPrevNext.Employee_ID = NextApp2.Terp_ID
           AND EmpPrevNext.NextApnt = NextApp2.app_DateTime

         JOIN hs_hr_employee as Emp2
            ON EmpPrevNext.Employee_ID = Emp2.Employee_ID
            JOIN orangehrm_li.ohrm_employment_status as EStat
               ON Emp2.Emp_Status = EStat.ID
               AND EStat.`name` = 'Active'

            JOIN hs_hr_emp_skill as EmpSkill
              ON Emp2.emp_number = EmpSkill.emp_number
              JOIN ohrm_skill as Skill
                 on EmpSkill.skill_id = Skill.id 
                AND Skill.`name` like '%Arabic%'
   order by 
      rand();
```

Make sure your appointment table has an index on (Terp_ID, app_datetime )